# Perform angularjs operation inside value attribute of html input tag

Tags: html, mysql, angularjs, laravel-5.1

I want to perform this operation but value attribute is not working

```
<input name="grand_total" type="text" class="form-control" value="@{{sum(saletemp)*discount1/100 | currency: "&#x9f3"}}" />

<input name="discount" type="text" class="form-control" id="add_payment"  ng-model="discount1"/>
```

Second question 
If I want to send value from a P tag after html form submission, how can I do that and how can I retrieve that value?
I want to pass this value `@{{sum(saletemp)*discount1/100 | currency: "&#x9f3"}}` to my controller and want to store it into my database. Here is the code portion

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="grand_total" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Discount</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
           <p class="form-control-static" ><b>@{{sum(saletemp)*discount1/100 | currency: "&#x9f3"}}</b></p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ? Did you get the solution?

Comment: @TirthrajBarot did it in a different way.

Comment: M out for a trip.. I ll get to you in 3 days

Answer (score 1):

You should use **ng-model** instead of dealing with the value attribute of input tag... That will provide you more flexibility for doing almost any kind of operation over it and accessing it in controller..

like `ng-model="saletemp"` will be available to you in controller as $scope.saletemp.. and if you want to call functions on some change in input tag value, you can simply call `ng-change="functionName()"` which you will have defined in controller as

```
 $scope.functionName = function(){YOUR FUNCTION DEFINITION}
```

Here is the fiddle which will allow you to put the currency in input tag when `ng-model` is used. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wNBAn/